# ActionBar Background Image in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Is it possible to set the background-image property of an ActionBar in NativeScript?

I know you can change the background color, but I'm not able to get a background image to show up.

I know you can do this in Native iOS and I'm sure in Android as well, how can it be done in {NS}?
I've checked the NS docs but it doesn't have anything on an actual background-image, only displaying images themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Page } from 'ui/page';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: 'modules/home/home.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private page : Page){

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.page.actionBar.backgroundImage = "res://actionbar_bg";
  }
}
```

**this one worked for me**